# Exposed filter autocomplete has TID with taxonomy term

Tags: views, 8

I created a view from taxonomy terms of different country names. I added an exposed filter to allow the user to enter the country, but when the user selects the country, it automatically adds the taxonomy ID after the name.

I've tried various things, from hooks to jQuery, I can't seem to figure out how to remove the TID. Please advise.

[image]

Comment: Take a look at  https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/200498/hide-the-term-id-on-autocomplete-widget

Comment: Or follow this https://www.chapterthree.com/blog/how-alter-entity-autocomplete-results-drupal-8 to alter the result of autocomplete as you like

Answer (score 0):

One solution can be custom javascript to remove the number from the result: like

```
(function($, Drupal, drupalSettings){
'use strict';

 Drupal.behaviors.my_module = {
   attach: function(context) {

  // Remove TID's onload.
  Drupal.my_module.remove_tid();

  // Remove TID's onchange.
  jQuery('body').find('#YOUR_FILTER_EXPOSED_ID').find('.form-autocomplete').on('autocompleteclose', function() {
    Drupal.my_module.remove_tid();
  });
}
};

Drupal.my_module = {
  remove_tid: function () {
    let field_autocomplete = jQuery('body').find('.form-autocomplete');
    let autocomplete_tid_stripped = field_autocomplete.val().split(' ')[0];
    field_autocomplete.val(autocomplete_tid_stripped);
  },
};

})(jQuery, Drupal, drupalSettings);
```

Another solution could be using [views_autocomplete_filter](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_autocomplete_filters) module, add a relation to your taxonomy term and instead of entity filter and a filter on  terms name, so there will not id there. a little slower but works.